# Clearing Data from specific Columns / Ranges using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to clear data from a template I've set up using VBA, the code I have written below is to clear specific columns and rows in Sheet 1 (Product Entry) but it comes back with a **Run Time Error 1004**.

Can someone please point out what I've missed.

```
Sub ClearCells()

    Range("B2:B200").ClearContents
    Range("C2:C200").ClearContents
    Range("E2:E200").ClearContents
    Range("G2:G200").ClearContents
    Range("H2:H200").ClearContents
    Range("J2:J200").ClearContents
    Range("L2:L200").ClearContents
    Range("M2:M200").ClearContents
    Range("N2:N200").ClearContents
    Range("O2:O200").ClearContents
    Range("Q2:Q200").ClearContents
    Range("R2:R200").ClearContents
    Range("S2:S200").ClearContents
    Range("T2:T200").ClearContents
    Range("U2:U200").ClearContents
    Range("V2:V200").ClearContents
    Range("W2:W200").ClearContents
    Range("X2:X200").ClearContents
    Range("Y2:Y200").ClearContents
    Range("Z2:Z200").ClearContents
    Range("AA2:AA200").ClearContents
    Range("AB2:AB200").ClearContents
    Range("AC2:AC200").ClearContents
    Range("AD2:AD200").ClearContents

    End Sub
```

Comment: This macro works fine for me. This error is caused by a security option in Excel meant to deliberately lock out programmatic access to Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) unless a user chooses to permit such access.



To resolve:

Open a blank workbook in Excel.
Go to File > Options > Trust Center
Click on Trust Center Settings... 
Under Macro Settings, make sure Trust access to the VBA project object model is checked.

Comment: Thanks Anthony, I've done this and I'm still getting this error message, any other suggestions?

Comment: Run-time Error 1004 can refer to different types of errors. Since you haven't qualified your range references, they'll refer to the active sheet. So maybe the active sheet is protected? Or, maybe the active sheet is a sheet other than a worksheet, such as a chart sheet? Exactly what type of error are you getting?

Comment: The Trust Center Settings changes now works, I just closed down everything and now it works. Thanks Anthony

Comment: Hi Domenc,the active sheet was protected and it came up with a 400 Error Code, but when I unprotected the active sheet the macro worked. Is there a way I can get the code to work with the active sheet protected as I don't want the users to touch the columns that have forumulas in?